# Radius of convergence of Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ around $z_0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Define $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}, z\ne \pm i$. Prove that if $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ where $z_0\ne\pm i$ then the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ around $z_0$ is $\sqrt{x_0^2+(1-|y_0|)^2}$.

Here is what I've got so far:

In general the Taylor series expansion is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n$. With $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ I am not sure how to compute this. If I knew this, I would then apply the ratio test and solve for $R$ but at the moment I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: Think about a geometric series.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I initially thought about that, but in order for it to converge we have $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ the common ratio - I can't seem to find the common ratio though - it's not a geometric sum either which makes it tricky

Comment: Stronger hint: write $\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-z)^2}.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You have $$\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z+i} + \frac{1}{z-i}\right)$$ and

$$\frac{1}{z+i} = \frac{1}{i+z_0}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{z-z_0}{i+z_0}}.$$

Finally, the radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{z-z_0}{i+z_0}}$ around $z_0$ is equal to $\left\vert i+z_0\right\vert$. And you can have the same approach for $\frac{1}{z-i}$.

Comment: Thanks! So if we have the radius of convergence for $\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-z_0}{i+z_0}}$ being $|i+z_0|=|x_0+i(1+y_0)|=\sqrt{x_0^2-(1+y_0)^2}$, how do we use the analogous result for $\frac{1}{z-i}$ to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Just replace $i$ with $-i$... to obtain $\vert -i + z_0 \vert$.

Comment: But how do we combine the two together?

Comment: Come on... you have to fill the dots now.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is defined on $D= \mathbb C \setminus \{i,-i\}$ and $f$ has poles of order $1$ in $i$ and $-i$ . If $z_0 \in D$, then it is known that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ around $z_0$ is given by

$$R= dist (z_0, \partial D).$$

Here: $\partial D=\{i,-i\}$ , hence

$$R= \min\{|z_0-i|,|z_0+i|\}.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: It's an approach, but I suspect the goal is to prove this from scratch in this specific case.